# Excel: Is there a way to count the number of non-empty columns in a given range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, multiple-columns

I have data in a worksheet that is divided up by multiple events, with each event getting its own column. The user can add columns as and when a new event takes place. I would like to determine the number of events by counting the total no. of non-empty columns in a given range. Is there a way to do this?

It would not do to count the non-empty cells in the first row of data in the given range because not all cells in the column are necessarily filled. Any pointers?

Edit: To be clear, I would like to look at whether a column is empty or not and count all those which are not. Some cells in the column are filled; some are not. What I'm trying to do is count all those columns in which at least one cell is filled. Hope that is more clear!

Comment: You seem to be asking for a formula to count all non-empty cells in each row.  However, the second part of your question says you can't count the non-empty cells, because they're not necessarily filled.  This sounds conflicted, but maybe you can [edit] your question with a before/after sample picture or additional anonymized sample data/details?

Comment: You could use a helper row that determines whether the column is empty or not.

Comment: I have edited the question above - hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array formula will count the number of columns in a set range that are not empty:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(A1:F9<>"")),ROW(A1:F9)^0)>0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a column is not empty with using: =COUNT('start':'end'). If there is a value inside one field, the count function will return the number of non empty elements. You can now check the fields containing the COUNT-functions with IF('count_field'>0;1;0). Now you have fields containing a 1 if the column has values and 0 if not. Next step is to SUM('start':'end') all the "IF"-fields. That should be the number of columns containing any value.